# VBA Loop Optimisation by Storing a Range as an Array?

Tags: arrays, vba, performance, loops, for-loop

I have a Function that calculates an average payout. The loop calculates down from x days to y days. As part of this function I have to interpolate a number using a specific range. However this is **very slow**.

I read that a method to speed up the code would be to read the range as values rather than a Range as VBA is slowed down by going to Excel each time the code is run.

Is this true?

My current code.

```
    Function AveragePayout(Time As Double, period)
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim sum As Double
        Dim interpolate_surface As Range        
        Set interpolate_surface = Range("A1", "D4")

        If Time < period Then
            AveragePayout = 0
        Else
            For i = 1 To period
                interpolated_val = Interpolation(interpolate_surface, 5, Time)
                sum = sum + CustomPricer(interpolated_value)
                Time = Time - 1
            Next i
            AveragePayout = sum / period
        End If
    End Function
```

I was thinking to change line 5 to the below to then run the Interpolation on an VBA matrix/array rather than returning to the Excel document each loop (which apparently slows the function tremendously:

```
Set interpolate_surface = Range("A1", "D4").Value2
```

Alternatively are there any other methods to speed up the running of this loop?

Many thanks.

Comment: if i remember correctly Range will be bind to excel sheet while in loop so that what makes it slow(you might know). Have you seen any improvement by reading the values and loop through . Is there any other reason you looking for performance improvement ????

Comment: Not an answer at all, but you should learn to use `Option Explicit`! That would avoid you to use `interpolated_val` on one line and `interpolated_value` on the next one. (and in the end that might provide  more value than accelerating the macro :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While R.Leruth is very close, there are a few things that need to be elaborated on.

First, the reason why a `Range` object is slower is because you are working on the `Object` representation of that value, and there are events bound to that `Range`. As a result, calculations will run, the sheet will need to be evaluated, and accessing the value has to go through the `Object`, and not through an in-memory representation of that object.

This performance decrease generally stands true for any `Range` operations, and the performance decrease is **directly** tied to the size of the range. Thus, operating on 100 cells is **much** quicker than operating on 1,000,000 cells.

While performance time of an array is also directly linked, accessing each value is **much** quicker. This is because the the values are in-memory and easy to access. There are no `Objects` to depend on with an array. This doesn't mean arrays will **always** be fast. I have encountered instances of array operations taking many minutes or hours because I took their initial speed for granted. You will notice a performance decrease with arrays, but the rate of performance decrease is **much much much** lower.

To create an array, we use the `Variant` type. Keep in mind a `Variant` can be anything, so you have to be somewhat careful. General convention is to use `Dim Foo as Variant()` but then any argument that accepts or returns a `Variant()` must be given a `Variant()` and not a `Variant` (minor difference, huge impact on code). Because of this, I tend to use `Dim Foo as Variant`.

We can then assign the **Values** from a range back to the array. While `Foo = Range("A1:B2")` is functionally equivalent to `Foo = Range("A1:B2").Value`, I **strongly** recommend *full qualification*. Thus, I don't rely on *implicit* properties as much as I can (`.Value` is the implicit property of `Range`).

So our code *should* be:

```
Dim Foo as Variant
Foo = SomeRange.Value
```

Where `Foo` is your variable, and `SomeRange` is replaced with your range.

As long as your `Interpolate` function accepts an `array`, this should cause no issues whatsoever. If the `Interpolate` function doesn't accept an `array`, you may need to find another workaround (or write your own).

To output the array, we just need to create a range of the same size as our array. There are different ways of doing this. I tend to prefer this method:

`SomeRange.Resize(UBound(SomeArray, 1) - LBound(SomeArray, 1) + 1, Ubound(SomeArray, 2) - LBound(SomeArray, 2) + 1)`

All this does is takes some range (should be a single cell) and resizes that range by the number of columns in the array, and the number of rows in the array. I use `(Ubound - Lbound) + 1` since, for a 0-based array, this will return `Ubound + 1` and for a 1-based array it will return `Ubound`. It makes things much simpler than creating `If` blocks for the same purpose.

The last thing to make sure in all of this is that your `Range` variable is fully-qualified. Notice that `Range("A1:B2").Value` is functionally equivalent to `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2").Value` but again, relying on implicit calls quickly introduces bugs. Squash those out as much as possible. If you need the `ActiveSheet` then use it. Otherwise, create a `Worksheet` variable and point that variable to the correct sheet.

And if you **must** use the `ActiveSheet` then `Dim Foo as Worksheet : Set Foo = ActiveSheet` is much better than just using the `ActiveSheet` (since the `ActiveSheet` will generally change when you really need it not to, and then everything will break.

Best of luck in using arrays. They are **performance changing** but they are never an excuse for bad coding practices. Make sure you use them properly, and that you aren't introducing new inefficiencies just because you now *can*.

Answer (score 1):

What we usually do in VBA to speed up macros is to decrease the amount of interaction between the code and the sheet.

For example :

1. Get all necessary values in an array

   ```
   Dim arr() as Variant
   arr = Range("A1:D4")
   ```
2. Treat the value

   ```
   ...
   ```
3. Put them back

   ```
   Range("A1:D4") = arr
   ```

In your case just try to change `interpolated_surface` from `Range` to an `array` type.

Comment: @RJ- A `Variant` is, by definition, pretty much *any* type. Thus it can take on the form of an array whether it is declared using `Foo as Variant()` (explicit array form) or `Foo as Variant` which requires `Foo` to now be directly assigned to an array type, such as in `Foo = SomeTwoDimensionalRange.Value`.